# how to merge two rows into one in spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I am stuck at a point in spotfire wherein I need to transform the table (the one below)

```
ID  First name  last name
1   Mark    
1               Taylor
2   Howard  
2               Giblin
```

to (the table as shown here)

```
ID First Name Last Name 
1  Mark       Taylor 
2  James      Bond
```

Could someone please help me out. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: is there a reason you can't fix this data before it enters spotfire?

Comment: You can use `MAX()` and group by the ID

Answer (score 1):

- File > Add Data Tables
- Add (button) > From Current Analysis > "Your Table Name"
- Under transformations, Select "Calculate and Replace Column" > Add (button)

Then use this formula

```
Max([FirstName]) over ([ID]) as [FirstName]
```

Repeat the last step for you last name

```
Max([LastName]) over ([ID]) as [LastName]
```

Note, you could do this in a cross table or a calculated column as well. It will not remove the duplicate rows though, only fill in the gaps.